# pyspark- count items that match for different key combinations

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, combinations

The problem is difficult for me to solve.

I need to count the number of matching items of variable "val" for each combination of variable "key", the database is like:

```
    +----------+----------------+
    |    key   |        val     |
    +----------+----------------+
    |        k1|         v1     |
    |        k1|         v2     |
    |        k2|         v1     |
    |        k2|         v3     |
    |        k3|         v1     |
    |        k3|         v2     |
    |        k3|         v3     |
    |        k4|         v3     |
    |        k4|         v5     |
    +----------+----------------+
```

the desired output is

```
    +----------+----------------+
    |    keys  |        count   |
    +----------+----------------+
    |   [k1,k2]|         1      |
    |   [k1,k3]|         2      |
    |   [k2,k1]|         1      |
    |   [k2,k3]|         2      |
    |   [k2,k4]|         1      |
    |   [k3,k1]|         2      |
    |   [k3,k2]|         2      |
    |   [k3,k4]|         1      |
    |   [k4,k2]|         1      |
    |   [k4,k3]|         1      |
    +----------+----------------+
```

The idea I have is a kind of groupBy and apply a complex function that returns what is desired, however, I have no idea how to do it, I would appreciate any suggestion that helps me find the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a self join using `val`, collect the keys into an array, and then group by the keys array and count.

```
results = df.join(
    df.withColumnRenamed('key', 'key2'),
    'val'
).filter('key != key2').select(
    F.array('key', 'key2').alias('keys'), 
    'val'
).groupBy('keys').count().orderBy('keys')

results.show()
+--------+-----+
|    keys|count|
+--------+-----+
|[k1, k2]|    1|
|[k1, k3]|    2|
|[k2, k1]|    1|
|[k2, k3]|    2|
|[k2, k4]|    1|
|[k3, k1]|    2|
|[k3, k2]|    2|
|[k3, k4]|    1|
|[k4, k2]|    1|
|[k4, k3]|    1|
+--------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for me, I managed to adapt it for the case when a third is required instead of a double in keys. I accepted your solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `left join on val` with the s*ame dataframe* (*df*) to achieve your desired output.

here is the *spark-sql* equivalent answer :

```
 df.createOrReplaceTempView('r')
 df.createOrReplaceTempView('l')

 desired_df = spark.sql('select array(l.key , r.key) as keys, count(l.val) as count from l left join r on l.val = r.val where l.key !=r.key group by 1)
```